# How to split url to multiple lines with indentation using bash

Tags: bash

Input url is
**url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation"**

I have tried the following way

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\
Corporation"
echo $url
```

***Output:***

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation
```

But I want this with indentation to have better visibility. Let's say suppose

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\
     Corporation"
echo $url
```

***Output:***

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ Corporation
```

Here after **wiki/** it is appended with space. How to eliminate this?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the indentation you want an remove the blanks prior printing/using the variable or after the variable declaration:

```sh
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\
    Corporation"
url=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$url")

echo $url
```

Prints:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation
```

---

**Update:** You can also do the following:

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\
    Corporation"

echo ${url// /}
```

Comment: this does the trick; only a pity to change the variable using an external process...

Comment: Makes you ask: "Was the indention really worth it?"

Comment: You can instead use `echo ${url// /}`

Comment: Then I have to use in this way ${url// /} If I want it in multiple places. Is there any other way which can be done using backslashes or someway while assigning value to variable(url). So that we can access $url in multiple places

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\n\tCorporation"
echo -e $url
```

output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
    Corporation
```

**edit**: note that you can adjust yourself using newlines (`\n`), tabs (`\t`) or spaces...

**edit2**: if you want a multiline variable; that is quite difficult, but you might do it like this; so you can indent the second line as much as you want.

```
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
    url="$url/Corporation"
echo $url
```

output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation
```

Comment: I want the output url to be in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation this format. But if we see the second example which I gave is appended with space after "wiki/". But when we assign a value to url that it should be indented so that it will have better visibility.

Comment: you're still not making it clear... you want a variable in multiline; but the output should be on one line? I'll add this to my answer if that is what you want...

Comment: lets make this simple. In my two examples. I want to use the code similar to second example but the output should be the one which first example provides. So I need help how to make changes to second example to do it.

Comment: well my second example has different code; but after the first two lines the variable has the value you wish it has (no spaces or whatsoever). If you really want to keep your two lines with indentation; you need to change the variable when printing it; so look at @higuaro's answer which does the trick